# Running from class in LinqPad

Tags: c#, linqpad

How can I run the code below in LinqPad as **C# Program**  Thank you...

```
class ThreadTest
{
    bool done;

    static void Main()
    {
        ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();   // Create a common instance
        new Thread (tt.Go).Start();
        tt.Go();
    }

    // Note that Go is now an instance method
    void Go() 
    {
        if (!done) { done = true; Console.WriteLine ("Done"); }
    }
}
```

> **UPDATE**
>
> This sample - along with all the others in the concurrency chapters of C# 5 in a Nutshell are downloadable as a LINQPad sample library. Go to LINQPad's samples TreeView and click 'Download/Import more samples' and choose the first listing. – Joe Albahari

Comment: Have you tried it?  What errors are you getting? Have you added a reference to System.Threading?

Comment: @DStanley it gives NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at LINQPad.ExecutionModel.ClrQueryRunner.Run() at LINQPad.ExecutionModel.Server.RunQuery(QueryRunner runner)

Comment: This sample - along with all the others in the concurrency chapters of C# 5 in a Nutshell are downloadable as a LINQPad sample library. Go to LINQPad's samples TreeView and click 'Download/Import more samples' and choose the first listing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move `Main` out of `ThreadTest` and it should work fine.  You also need to make the class and method `public` (or `internal` at that point):

```
static void Main()
{
   ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();   // Create a common instance
   new Thread (tt.Go).Start();
   tt.Go();
}

public class ThreadTest
{
    bool done;
    // Note that Go is now an instance method
    public void Go() 
    {
        if (!done) { done = true; Console.WriteLine ("Done"); }
    }
}
```

The "C# Program" is implicitly contained inside a class - moving `main` inside a nested class is probably confusing the executor which is looking for `Main` in the outermost class.

Comment: uppss I'm sorry Stanley my bad, I copied/pasted wrong sample but  updated now.